# Jdk security setup unexpected token

Tags: java

I'm Trying setup JDK Security Certificate. I copied Certificate c:\cer.cer from browser. Further I'm Trying this

```
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_141"
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool" -import -alias nexussrv -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -file c:\cer.cer
```

I get an error

```
Set-Variable : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'import'.
At line:1 char:84
+ ... es (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_141" "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool" -import -alias  
...
+                                                           ~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Variable], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetVariableCommand
```

Or

```
At line:1 char:28
+  "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool" -import -alias nexussrv -keystore "%JAVA_H ...
+                            ~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '-import' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:36
+  "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool" -import -alias nexussrv -keystore "%JAVA_H ...
+                                    ~~~~~~
Unexpected token '-alias' in expression or statement.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], 
ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if %JAVA_HOME% is set properly or not in command prompt before executing the command. If java home path is wrong means, it won't identify -import and -alias parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked my scripts and they use '-importcert' parameter, not 'import'... just as described in this link for Java 8 toolchain: "https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html"

Comment: `Set-Variable : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'importcert'.
At line:1 char:84
+ ... x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_141" "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool" -importcert -alias  ...
+                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Variable], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetVariableCommand